# Change the color of the ResizeGrip in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the color of the `ResizeGrip`'s squares, but I can't find the right property.

I tried overriding the default ResizeGrip style as follow:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackground}" />
</Style>
```

I suppose the ControlTemplate is too complex to be able to reach that property from the TemplatedParent.

So, am I supposed to override the ControlTemplate ? Get the grip by code ? Or is there something easier that I missed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we go check out the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we see not only are those properties not template bound, they have a hard set "Transparent" in there. So we can just take up the slack;

**EDIT**

```
<Style x:Key="blah" TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Width="10"
                    Height="10">
                <Path Data="M7.677,7.5300003 L9.677,7.5300003 9.677,9.5300002 7.677,9.5300002 z M3.786,7.5300003 L5.7859998,7.5300003 5.7859998,9.5300002 3.786,9.5300002 z M0,7.5300003 L2,7.5300003 2,9.5300002 0,9.5300002 z M3.786,3.8280003 L5.7859998,3.8280003 5.7859998,5.8280003 3.786,5.8280003 z M7.677,3.7660003 L9.677,3.7660003 9.677,5.7659999 7.677,5.7659999 z M7.677,0 L9.677,0 9.677,2 7.677,2 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="9.53" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9.677"/>
             </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now you can go make it whatever you want;

```
<ResizeGrip Foreground="Red" Style="{StaticResource blah}"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Alright, it seems if I change the `<Rectangle>`'s brush property I might achieve my goal. I'll try it as soon as I can.

Comment: Changing the color works, but the shape of the grip has changed from a triangle to a square. Is there a way to use the default (native) shape ?

Comment: I don't remember it ever being a triangle. If you'd rather change the color of the `Rectangle` then you can just move the TemplateBinding for Background over to the `Fill` property of the Rectangle. All that template is literally is copy/pasted from the msn docs for the default template with a Background property added to the template, nothing fancy.

Comment: [This is what the default resize grip looks like in my Windows 8.1](http://i.imgur.com/V9ajNva.jpg). The template you (and so MSDN) provided makes it look like a square made of littles squares, instead of the triangle.

Comment: @Chnossos wait, are you making a windows store app or wpf?

Comment: I'm making a WPF app, if the colours are troubling you I just applied a dark theme to my MainWindow.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how you're seeing a triangle? Nothing in that template would have changed anything like that. Maybe if you post a quick image of what you want as opposed to what you see, this really isn't this difficult of a task.

Comment: The link to the image I posted above is a screen of the **default** grip I see when I don't modify the template. Using the template you provided in your answer, I get [**this**](http://i.imgur.com/9ODKSX9.jpg). See the difference ?

Comment: Hahaha seriously, those little dots in the corner is what you were talking about this whole time? That should be simple enough to remedy, hell I think just adding the property like [CanResizeWithGrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the ResizeMode will do that to the adorner, or either way it's not hard to change those dots amigo.

Comment: Well, those little dots **are** the grip I want to change the color of :D And they appear **because** I set `ResizeMode` to `CanResizeWithGrip`. So now, I can change the color by applying my own template, but I want to keep the default way these dots appear, is that possible ?

Comment: Of course it's possible, you want to change the color of the dots, and not the background? It's real easy to pull out that single rectangle that's using a Drawing Brush and use Path geometry or individual small rectangles with their Fill bound to the template.

Comment: _you want to change the color of the dots, and not the background_ Yes that's what I want to do. Sorry for being unclear from the start, I shouldn't have had presented an attempt with the `Background` property ...

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I'm back from holiday if not.

Comment: Well I'm basically stuck at the same point, so no this question hasn't got an acceptable answer yet.

Comment: @Chnossos see my updated answer, tested and works fine, you just needed your little blocks.

Comment: Cool beans, glad you got your remedy, happy holidays! :)